# Installing ctrlp in VIM using vundle

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vundle, ctrlp

I'm using [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) as my plugin manager for vim.

However I'm having trouble installing [ctrlp plugin](http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim/).

When I execute `:BundleInstall ctrlp`, it outputs the following log with a fatal error:

> [131003 09:39:27] Bundle kien/ctrlp
>   [131003 09:39:27] $ git clone --recursive
>   'https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.git' '/home/username/.vim/bundle/ctrlp'
>   [131003 09:39:27] > Cloning into
>   '/home/username/.vim/bundle/ctrlp'...^@fatal:
>   https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.git/info/ refs?service=git-upload-pack
>   not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?^@
>   [131003 09:39:28] Helptags:
>   [131003 09:39:28] :helptags /home/username/.vim/bundle/vundle/doc/
>   [131003 09:39:28] :helptags
>   /home/username/.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive/doc/
>   [131003 09:39:28] :helptags
>   /home/username/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized/doc/
>   [131003 09:39:28] :helptags /home/username/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/doc/
>   [131003 09:39:28] Helptags: 4 bundles processed
>   [131003 09:49:39] Bundle ctrlp
>   [131003 09:49:39] $ git clone --recursive
>   'https://github.com/vim-scripts/ctrlp.git'
>   '/home/username/.vim/bundle/ctrlp'
>   [131003 09:49:39] > Cloning into
>   '/home/username/.vim/bundle/ctrlp'...^@fatal:
>   https://github.com/vim-scripts/ctrlp.gi
>   t/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git
>   update-server-info on the server?^@ [131003 09:49:40] Helptags:
>   [131003 09:49:40] :helptags /home/username/.vim/bundle/vundle/doc/
>   [131003 09:49:40] :helptags
>   /home/username/.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive/doc/
>   [131003 09:49:40] :helptags
>   /home/username/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized/doc/
>   [131003 09:49:40] :helptags /home/username/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/doc/
>   [131003 09:49:40] Helptags: 4 bundles processed
>   [131003 09:50:12] Bundle ctrlp
>   [131003 09:50:12] $ git clone --recursive
>   'https://github.com/vim-scripts/ctrlp.git'
>   '/home/username/.vim/bundle/ctrlp'
>   [131003 09:50:12] > Cloning into
>   '/home/username/.vim/bundle/ctrlp'...^@fatal:
>   https://github.com/vim-scripts/ctrlp.gi
>   t/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git
>   update-server-info on the server?^@
>   [131003 09:50:13] Helptags:
>   [131003 09:50:13] :helptags /home/username/.vim/bundle/vundle/doc/
>   [131003 09:50:13] :helptags
>   /home/username/.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive/doc/
>   [131003 09:50:13] :helptags
>   /home/username/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized/doc/
>   [131003 09:50:13] :helptags /home/username/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/doc/
>   [131003 09:50:13] Helptags: 4 bundles processed

Here is my .vimrc:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax enable
set background=light
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set nocompatible               " be iMproved
filetype off                   " required!

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

" let Vundle manage Vundle
" required! 
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'

" My Bundles here:
"
" original repos on github
Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Bundle 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Bundle 'vbundles/ctrlp'

colorscheme solarized
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**UPDATE September 2015:**

The kien/ctrlp.vim repo is out of date, what you really want is [this currently maintained fork](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim).

The correct line in your .vimrc is now:

`Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'`

**OLD ANSWER:**

To install CtrlP with Vundle, the correct line in your .vimrc is now:

`Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'`

Note that the `.vim` is necessary.

Comment: +1. Although this isn't an answer for this particular question, but I was not able to install CtrlP exactly because of this and this was the gotcha! Dunno why .vim is necessary in this case, can you please explain it?

Comment: @0xc0de this is because Vundle pulls from the github repo and the repo is at https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim. Note the trailing `.vim`

Vim plugins rarely contain a `.vim` after the name which is why it's easy to get mixed up with CtrlP.

Answer (score 8):

You are not using the right source, that `vbundles/ctrlp` thing is of no use. The *real* CtrlP is:

```
https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim
```

Alternatively, you can do the cloning yourself.

Comment: You are right, I've fixed the problem using `kien/ctrlp`as bundle in my .vimrc config

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a different repo.  What's the general reason for that message?

Comment: As of time of the comment, actively maintained version of CtrlP is moved here: http://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say this , but non of the above worked for me. Here is how i did it with the help of [vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim)

1) `install vundle` "read more about , it is just a package manager for vim".

2) `start vim .`

3) typed `:PluginSearch ctrlP`

After hitting enter , `one plugin found`

You will see this .

```
Keymap: i - Install plugin; c - Cleanup; s - Search; R - Reload list                  
"Search results for: ctrlP                                                             + Plugin 'ctrlp.vim'
```

Of course , proceed with the `i` to install .

Make sure it is installed successfully - in vim key in .

```
  :help ctrlP
```

You should see this :

```
*ctrlp.txt*       Fuzzy file, buffer, mru, tag, ... finder. v1.79
*CtrlP* *ControlP* *'ctrlp'* *'ctrl-p'*
===============================================================================
#                                                                             #
#          :::::::: ::::::::::: :::::::::  :::             :::::::::          #
#         :+:    :+:    :+:     :+:    :+: :+:             :+:    :+:         #
#         +:+           +:+     +:+    +:+ +:+             +:+    +:+         #
#         +#+           +#+     +#++:++#:  +#+             +#++:++#+          #
#         +#+           +#+     +#+    +#+ +#+             +#+                #
#         #+#    #+#    #+#     #+#    #+# #+#             #+#                #
#          ########     ###     ###    ### ##########      ###                #
#                                                                             #
===============================================================================
CONTENTS                                                       *ctrlp-contents*
```

EDIT:

You will also need to add it to your `vimrc`

```
za:~ za$ vim ~/.vimrc

#add this to your vimrc file
Plugin 'ctrlp.vim'
```

Start vim , and from the command type:

```
:PluginList
```

you will a list installed plugins

```
" My Plugins                            |
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'           |~                                      
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'             |~                                      
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.|~                                      
git'                                    |~                                      
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup'               |~                                      
Plugin 'ascenator/L9'                   |~                                      
Plugin 'ctrlp.vim'                      |~                                      
                                        |~                                      
~
```

enjoy!!